# Populating a JavaFx Fxml Toolbar with Graphics Buttons

Tags: javafx, fxml

I have been endeavoring to implement a *JavaFX* application using FXML which includes a toolbar in the bottom region of a `BorderPane` populated with four buttons displaying graphics only.

However, the buttons are displayed in gray outline only with no graphic content.

A simplified snippet of the FXML file is as follows:

```
<bottom>
    <ToolBar fx:id="tbTextColor" >
        <Button fx:id="btnRed"   contentDisplay="GRAPHIC_ONLY">
            <graphic>
                <ImageView>
                    <image>
                        <Image url="@red.png"> </Image>
                    </image>
                </ImageView>
            </graphic>
        </Button>

        <!--more buttons-->

    </ToolBar>
</bottom>
```

If anybody can inform me how to achieve the desired result, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: As explained in the document [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html), according to the snippet in your question, file `red.png` needs to be in the same folder as the FXML file. Is it?

Comment: Yes, ```red.png``` is in the same folder as the fxml file.

Comment: It works for me when I put the FXML file and the image file in the same folder as the [compiled] java application. Let's say I have class `App` which is my JavaFX application. Then the FXML file and file `red.png` must be in the same folder as file `App.class`. If you post a [mcve] that may help me understand which folders contain which files since that should contain the code for loading your FXML file, including the URL of the FXML file. I see no error in the FXML snippet that you posted in your question.

Comment: Check the image is being deployed to the build folder, and is in the same subfolder of the build folder as the FXML file (i.e. check the file structure in the build, not just in the source).

Comment: @Abra @James_D Thank you both. `red.png` was not being deployed to the Build folder. When attempting to create a minimal reproducible example the original files were copied to a new project, recompiled and rerun. The toolbar buttons displayed as expected, so all good now. Your assistance is much appreciated.